# How to overlay density plots in R?

Tags: r, plot, density-plot

I would like to overlay 2 density plots on the same device with R. How can I do that? I searched the web but I didn't find any obvious solution.

My idea would be to read data from a text file (columns) and then use

```
plot(density(MyData$Column1))
plot(density(MyData$Column2), add=T)
```

Or something in this spirit.

Comment: For `ggplot2` family, there is now a package "[`ggridges`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html)" that can do this.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

use `lines` for the second one:

```
plot(density(MyData$Column1))
lines(density(MyData$Column2))
```

make sure the limits of the first plot are suitable, though.

Comment: +1 You might need something slightly more complex when the two densities have different ranges and the second curve doesn't fit within the plot limits. Then you can compute the densities before plotting, and compute an appropriate `ylim` using `range(dens1$y, dens2$y)` where `dens1` and `dens2` are the objects containing the two density estimation objects. Use this `ylim` in the call to `plot()`.

Comment: You will probably also want to distinguish between the two lines. Setting the line width (`lwd`), line type (`lty`) or the line color (`col`) should help here. At that point, you might also consider adding a legend, using `legend()`

Comment: @Gavin If the OP is reading from a file, I would construct an elaborate function that would read in data (sapply, lapply), find ranges of all data sets, set the default range to the max range of all and then plot (lines) the densities.

Answer (score 52):

[ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) is another graphics package that handles things like the range issue Gavin mentions in a pretty slick way. It also handles auto generating appropriate legends and just generally has a more polished feel in my opinion out of the box with less manual manipulation.

```
library(ggplot2)

#Sample data
dat <- data.frame(dens = c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 10, 5))
                   , lines = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 100))
#Plot.
ggplot(dat, aes(x = dens, fill = lines)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: The OP's data.frame needs to be molten to long form first: `ggplot (melt (MyData), mapping = aes (fill = variable, x = value)) + geom_density (alpha = .5)`

Comment: Nice plot.  What's "dat2" ... ?  what's "melt" (command not found) ?

Comment: @ErikAronesty - you're guess is as good as mine at this point, I answered this two years ago! I speculate that I had another object named `dat` in my environment so named it `dat2`...the simulated data I provide works as advertised though. the `melt()` command comes from package `reshape2`. Back in 2011, `reshape2` was automatically loaded when `ggplot2` was loaded, but that's no longer the case so you need to do `library(reshape2)` separately.

Answer (score 24):

Adding base graphics version that takes care of y-axis limits, add colors and works for any number of columns:

If we have a data set:

```
myData <- data.frame(std.nromal=rnorm(1000, m=0, sd=1),
                     wide.normal=rnorm(1000, m=0, sd=2),
                     exponent=rexp(1000, rate=1),
                     uniform=runif(1000, min=-3, max=3)
                     )
```

Then to plot the densities:

```
dens <- apply(myData, 2, density)

plot(NA, xlim=range(sapply(dens, "[", "x")), ylim=range(sapply(dens, "[", "y")))
mapply(lines, dens, col=1:length(dens))

legend("topright", legend=names(dens), fill=1:length(dens))
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: I like this example, but if you have columns of data that includes NA values it does not work. I'm unsure how to modify the code, but this would be useful

Comment: @daisy change this line `dens <- apply(myData, 2, density)` to `dens <- apply(myData, 2, density, na.rm=TRUE)` and it should work.

Answer (score 13):

Just to provide a complete set, here's a version of Chase's answer using `lattice`:

```
dat <- data.frame(dens = c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 10, 5))
                   , lines = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 100))

densityplot(~dens,data=dat,groups = lines,
            plot.points = FALSE, ref = TRUE, 
            auto.key = list(space = "right"))
```

which produces a plot like this:
[image]

Comment: Without creating new `data.frame`: `densityplot(~rnorm(100)+rnorm(100, 10, 5), plot.points=FALSE, ref=TRUE, auto.key = list(space = "right"))`. Or for OP data `densityplot(~Column1+Column2, data=myData)`.

Answer (score 9):

That's how I do it in base (it's actually mentionned in the first answer comments but I'll show the full code here, including legend as I can not comment yet...)

First you need to get the info on the max values for the y axis from the density plots. So you need to actually compute the densities separately first

```
dta_A <- density(VarA, na.rm = TRUE)
dta_B <- density(VarB, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Then plot them according to the first answer and define min and max values for the y axis that you just got. (I set the min value to 0)

```
plot(dta_A, col = "blue", main = "2 densities on one plot"), 
     ylim = c(0, max(dta_A$y,dta_B$y)))  
lines(dta_B, col = "red")
```

Then add a legend to the top right corner

```
legend("topright", c("VarA","VarB"), lty = c(1,1), col = c("blue","red"))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `ggjoy` package. Let's say that we have three different `beta` distributions such as:

```
set.seed(5)
b1<-data.frame(Variant= "Variant 1", Values = rbeta(1000, 101, 1001))
b2<-data.frame(Variant= "Variant 2", Values = rbeta(1000, 111, 1011))
b3<-data.frame(Variant= "Variant 3", Values = rbeta(1000, 11, 101))


df<-rbind(b1,b2,b3)
```

You can get the three different distributions as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggjoy)


ggplot(df, aes(x=Values, y=Variant))+
    geom_joy(scale = 2, alpha=0.5) +
    scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0.01, 0)) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0.01, 0)) +
    theme_joy()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I took the above lattice example and made a nifty function. There is probably a better way to do this with reshape via melt/cast. (Comment or edit if you see an improvement.)

```
multi.density.plot=function(data,main=paste(names(data),collapse = ' vs '),...){
  ##combines multiple density plots together when given a list
  df=data.frame();
  for(n in names(data)){
    idf=data.frame(x=data[[n]],label=rep(n,length(data[[n]])))
    df=rbind(df,idf)
  }
  densityplot(~x,data=df,groups = label,plot.points = F, ref = T, auto.key = list(space = "right"),main=main,...)
}
```

Example usage:

```
multi.density.plot(list(BN1=bn1$V1,BN2=bn2$V1),main='BN1 vs BN2')

multi.density.plot(list(BN1=bn1$V1,BN2=bn2$V1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever there are issues of mismatched axis limits, the right tool in `base` graphics is to use `matplot`. The key is to leverage the `from` and `to` arguments to `density.default`. It's a bit hackish, but fairly straightforward to roll yourself:

```
set.seed(102349)
x1 = rnorm(1000, mean = 5, sd = 3)
x2 = rnorm(5000, mean = 2, sd = 8)

xrng = range(x1, x2)

#force the x values at which density is
#  evaluated to be the same between 'density'
#  calls by specifying 'from' and 'to'
#  (and possibly 'n', if you'd like)
kde1 = density(x1, from = xrng[1L], to = xrng[2L])
kde2 = density(x2, from = xrng[1L], to = xrng[2L])

matplot(kde1$x, cbind(kde1$y, kde2$y))
```

[image: A plot depicting the output of the call to matplot. Two curves are observed, one red, the other black; the black curve extends higher than the red, while the red curve is the "fatter".]

Add bells and whistles as desired (`matplot` accepts all the standard `plot`/`par` arguments, e.g. `lty`, `type`, `col`, `lwd`, ...).