# overlaying different density curves without showing the histogram

Tags: r

I want to be able to show three different density curves on the same axis. I've got the code below so far but i don't know how to combine them to so that they can

```
curve(dnorm(x,mean=0,sd=1),col="darkgreen",xlim=c(-4,8),ylim=c(0,.8))
curve(dnorm(x,mean = 0,sd=1.5),col="red",xlim = c(-5,8),ylim=c(0,.6))
curve(dnorm(x,mean = 0.5,sd=0.5),col="black",xlim = c(-2,8), ylim =c(0,1))
```

Comment: Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939136/how-to-overlay-density-plots-in-r

Comment: If you include `add=TRUE` in the second and third calls to `curve`, they will all appear in the same plot.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic solution. You can add more formatting if need be (for axes etc). Note you need to change the `xlim` and `ylim` to match on the plots.

```
curve(dnorm(x,mean=0,sd=1),col="darkgreen",xlim=c(-5,8),ylim=c(0,1), ylab = "")
par(new = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x,mean = 0,sd=1.5),col="red",xlim = c(-5,8),ylim=c(0,1), ylab = "")
par(new = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x,mean = 0.5,sd=0.5),col="black",xlim = c(-5,8), ylim =c(0,1), ylab = "")
```